# how to use mpg123 in android

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface

i am working on a MP 3 Player which contains changing the Pitch and Speed of playing MP 3  , so that i have to feed PCM to AudioTrack ,which leads to convert Mp 3 to PCM.
now after lots of Research on Google i Understand that there is Two ways to do this,one is using jlayer library
and other is using Native Libs i have read that the second Approach is quite Efficient ,and thing is i am new in native codes,so i read all about how to use native libs in android and successfully able to run native code examples on by eclipse my making jni and .mk and all.. now i am having problem in implementing mpg123 library in my Eclipse Android Project  ..i have read many people have done this previously...any help would be appreciative.. thanks in advance ...sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, see this code in github https://github.com/tulskiy/camomile

Comment: no..it doesn't solve my problem ..errors in every file in the projects and i think 2 or 3 libraries are missing.